# Read through my app's Core Data files (.sqlite, .sqlite-wal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to browse through the data written by Core Data in an iOS app I am developing.

After the app ran for a while, and I assume collected some data, I now wish to look through the data and see what was written.

I have tried getting and browsing the `.sqlite` file through getting the app container from the device (*Xcode > Devices > myApp > Download Container...*).

I got the db files, `myAppDB.sqlite`, `myAppDB.sqlite-shm` and `myAppDB.sqlite-wal`.

When trying to look through them, it seems like the `.sqlite` is an empty table (except maybe some generic CoreData/sqlite stuff), and the `-wal` file has all the info.

The thing is I was only able to know that the `wal` has useful data when opening it with TextEdit, which din't show it in a very readable way, and when I tried to use an SQLite Manager app I an alert saying the `wal` is encrypted and I am asked to put a password...

For what it matters, I am writing a framework which handles the db (the model file and the code for writing data is inside the framework), then I have this framework running in an app I am developing. This is the code I use to create the store from within the framework (using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)):

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
[MagicalRecord setDefaultModelNamed:@"myAppStore.momd" inBundle:frameworkBundle];

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myAppStoreDB.sqlite"];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL:storeURL];
```

**UPDATE:** I managed to open the `sqlite` file with both [Core-Data-Editor](https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor) and [CoreDataUtility](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility) but they both override and delete the contents of the `.wal` file, and show an empty table... It does have the model (entity names/properties etc.) but no data.

My `wal` file is 873KB but when I open the `sqlite` with one of these 2 tools it becomes 0Bytes...

**tl;dr**

How can I browse through the info written by Core Data of the app I am developing?

Comment: I believe it is encrypted and signed by you to prevent privacy issues when deployed.

Comment: @Schemetrical Yes I assumed that, but given the fact that I have never explicitly signed/encrypted it, it is done with some default configuration that I couldn't figure out how to decrypt... And this is where I need help...

Comment: Neither file is encrypted. As long as you didn't break the connection between the `.sqlite` file and the `-wal` file, all data should be visible if you open the `.sqlite` file with SQLite Manager (even without a [checkpoint](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt)).

Comment: the `wal` is being deleted when I open the `sqlite` file, please see the `UPDATE` in my question. What do you mean by "didn't break to connection"?

Comment: Personally for SQLite I use [Base - SQLite Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base-sqlite-editor/id402383384?mt=12).

Comment: @Zaph looks pretty good! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for some reason I had to force not using WAL in my store (using `@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"` as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1809/_index.html)).

I then got only `.sqlite` file without the `smh` and `wal` files, and was able to open it and view the data using the 2 mentioned tools (Core-Data-Editor and CoreDataUtility).

My guess is that this is something to do with either the fact that I am dealing with CoreData from a framework (creating a `moc`, creating entities, saving etc.) and not from the application. Another guess is that it has something to do with the fact that I am using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).

Any insights regarding the cause would be appreciated...

Comment: With MagicalRecord, if I call one of the methods to persist the data to disk, such as ``MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion`` then the data is flushed from the WAL to the actual sqlite file. See https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html for more info on the Write-Ahead-Logfile